# DS-160 Security and Background Information for UK Banned Applicants

Tags: visas, usa, uk, visa-bans

I'd like to know whether the question in DS-160 form implies other country refusals as well? In 2009, I was refused and banned by UK for future applications for 10 years since they did not find my language requirement document genuine.

I have been currently working for a global company and thus need to travel to US with B1/B2 visa; however, I do not actually know what to answer for below question:

"Have you ever sought to obtain or assist others to obtain a visa, entry into the United States, or any other United States immigration benefit by fraud or willful misrepresentation or other unlawful means?"

Does that question related with my current situation? I sought advice from my company's own visa department, and they told me that related question is only for United States applications and thus need be answered as "No".

I would gladly answer “Yes” and explain my situation rather than misrepresent myself, but would like to get your advice about the situation as well as I am not comfortable giving unnecessary details if it is not mandatory.

Regards,

Update: As of 2019, I succesfully been granted a visa to US for my business travel. Answered the question "No" like suggested here if anyone's wondering. Please note that application been done after my ban for UK expired, though I am not sure if it is effected anything at all.

Comment: It is ironic that the UK determined that your language skills document was not genuine and you are now posting a question about such a subtle distinction in english meaning. It does indeed seem to ask about any visa anywhere, but likely only intends to ask about USA immigration matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DS-160: Nonimmigrant Visa Application has just the one question in the section Immigration Law Violation Information:

> Have you ever sought to obtain or assist others to obtain a visa, entry into the United States, or any other United States immigration benefit by fraud or willful misrepresentation or other unlawful means?

In this case, the question relates to [Section 212 [8 U.S.C. 1182] of the US Immigration and Nationality Act](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-2006.html), and only applies to fraud and willful misrepresentation under United States immigration laws.

Thus, as you describe your backstory, your answer would be no, if you either never before applied for a US visa or applied successfully and was truthful throughout. A yes response would apply only if you have a previous US visa application, and included anything that was not true, whether it was a statement (e.g., when answering a question, written or verbal) or documents (e.g., fake or altered).

For clarification, do check your UK paperwork and make sure that the action actually invoked the ban and not that you were advised that a future application would, after refusal. If it states that you were refused under the Immigration Rules Appendix V 3.6 (false representations), you can state that you were refused, as opposed that you have a ban. While serious, it can be an important distinction when applying for visas and a bit less burdensome than a ban.

During the rest of the US visa process, including consular interview and biometrics, you will likely have the opportunity, and obligation, to disclose the UK refusal/ban. Wisely, you appreciate the importance and implication. Overlook that detail and your answer to the very same question in any future US visa application would have to be yes, that there was ‘’willful misrepresentation’ by silence or omission.

Comment: The OP is under no obligation to disclose his UK refusal unless specifically asked. The material willful misrepresentation by silence does not apply here. https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/Print/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ.html

Comment: Hi Giorgio and greatone. Thanks for your comments. I have yet to apply any US visa before. Only have 3 years of Schengen and other traveled countries’ visas. I would check the document of UK ban; however, it appears like I am unable to reach it after 9 years. But I do remember that the ban invoked and was stating that my future applications would be automatically refused under 320 (7b) till 2019. Since I am aware UK and US share info, did not want to trigger an alert for my character for false information for a case happened when I was just a student. (It was a student visa application for UK)

Comment: As of late 2019, I succesfully been granted a visa to US for my business travel. Answered the question "No" like suggested here if anyone's wondering. Please note that application been done after my ban for UK expired, though I am not sure if it is effected anything at all. Thanks for the help Giorgio and everyone.